# Redislabs UI logging error when number of nodes more than one

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, node-redis, redis-cluster, redislabs

I am new at Redis Enterprise and can't fix this problem:

I have a Redis Enterprise cluster (v.6.0) in AWS with two nodes. When I have only one node I can enter UI, but after adding other (second) nodes always throws me out to the login page after entering credentials. Meanwhile, the cluster works fine (information is taken from **rladmin**).

In what direction I should investigate the issue?

P.S.: Can this error from logs cause an issue?

`ERROR redis_mgr MainThread: Connect failed: connect: connection failed: Error 2 connecting to unix socket: /var/opt/redislabs/run/ccs.sock. No such file or directory.: retrying`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly, this solution will help anybody:

- the reason was that ALB before UI didn't use sticky sessions.
- the solution was to enable a sticky session and it works.
  [image]